# OnNavigationListener call

Tags: android, listener

I'm implementing NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST on my Activity ActionBar. My problem is that when I set up the OnNavigationListener on the ActionBar with setListNavigationCallbacks() the code of the 
listener is executed.

```
mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter,
            new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                        long itemId) {

                   ...

                }
            }
    );
```

I think this is correct because the system make a call to that listener to select the first item of my adapter, but I want to execute this code only when the user select an item of the list and not the first time.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise a lastPosition variable to 0 when the activity is created, you can then compare this value to the itemPosition in the onNavigationItemSelected method. If the values are different then the user has made a new choice, if they're the same then the user selected the same item (or this is the call from the list being initialised).